# Acceleration of Rain drop

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration

Under the heading 'Points to remember',my textbook states:

> It is possible that an object can be increasing in speed when its acceleration is decreasing as in case of a raindrop.

I could not get why acceleration of the raindrop is decreasing. Should not it be constant as acceleration due to gravity  is constant? Or there is some misprinting in the book?`Please help.

Answer (score 3):

The total force acting on a raindrop equals $g$ minus air resistance which increases with velocity. In other words, as the raindrop speeds up, air resistance increases which decreases the acceleration (until eventually the acceleration equals zero and terminal velocity has been reached).